# Unable to write to etc/utmp: there is not enough space in filesystem

Tags: aix

The ABC/hd4 filesystem which is mounted on /, was full somedays back.I tried to login today but got the following result ,

> telnet failed to write to etc/utmp: there is not enough space in filesystem  .. dev/pts/1 : 3004-004 You must login from the lowest login shell

After that I logged in after some time, but this time I was able to login, I checked and saw /hd4 was still full.What step should I take to avoid such things in future , without increasing allocated space.Also what unused files can be deleted from the /hd4 filesystem. Kindly suggest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all UNIX based systems it is dangerous to let / fill up. Not only could you not log in, but its possible that the server/applications will stop working. Its hard to be precise without knowing the server details but you need to ensure almost nothing is written to /. Normally the problem is that other logical volumes are being used to keep data out of / so applications are just being installed there and dumping data.
So the first recommendation would be take a review of the set-up of the server and how its configured, then work from there. It might require some application down time to get it all sorted, but its going to better than random crashes.